# US phone numbers

Tags: formatting, phone-number

I'm building an app that uses phone numbers to perform different tasks, and recently I've had quite a few requests to implement it for the US market. Unfortunately as I live in the UK I don't have much knowledge of US phone number formats, and with so many USA users on here I was hoping some of you would be able to help.

I'm looking to obtain a list of sample phone numbers as they appear in your call log on your mobile phones. I'm trying to determine if they come through in the format +1234567, +001234567, 001234567, 01234567, 1234567, 234567 etc, or perhaps the format can vary..

Hopefully you're hesitant about giving out phone numbers on the web, so feel free to change a few digits (I'm mainly interested in the first few digits and the format of the numbers).

The more numbers you can provide the better, thanks!

Comment: Interesting question :) I've seen articles on the standard number format (wikipedia has one on the north american format) but I've not seen someone actually ask how people and systems tend to form them.

Comment: Thanks! It's been a nightmare getting things working just in the UK.. some phone numbers come through as 07712 123123, others as +447712 123123, 447712123123, 0447712123123 and also 00447712123123! There doesn't seem to be any consistency at all! It'll be interesting to see what the US has to offer ;)

Comment: I guess I'd strip spaces to start with, but from then on -- I guess you can always assume that you've got a right-most part of the number, and that any missing left-most parts represent increasingly wider geographic areas ...

Comment: Note that +1 is a country code, whereas the “1” often seen preceding a phone number is just the long-distance dialing code. It doesn’t matter much in practice, but is good to know. For comparison UK phone numbers are sometimes shown with a leading “0” but you must omit that when dialing internationally. For US numbers, you would “omit the 1 (dialing code) from the beginning, and add a 1 (country code) to the beginning.” Since they are both “1” the result is identical.

Comment: I think that ^^ means "good luck, this might be a rough ride :)"

Comment: Yeah that makes sense Nate, I guess I'll take Tim's advice and strip the spaces (along with any brackets etc), then try and put all the numbers in the international format for consistency. I knew the +1 is the country code for the US, just didn't know whether it sometimes appeared on calls from within the country. If you were wondering why I was asking this it's for an Android app called Huru - http://www.blackroc-technology.com/huru. One country down, only a few hundred to go!

Comment: I'll put it in as an actual answer ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following formats are common:

```
+12312322334
2312322334
(231) 232-2334
2322334
232-2334
```

The last two forms are unusual, though may be encountered. The area code is implied to be local to the phone.

Note that there are some invalid entries: Numbers never start with a "1" (thats the long distance dial indicator, optional on cell phones), the "555" prefix is reserved (so commonly used in movies).

Comment: Thanks for that, great start! Interesting to know about the local area formats, I didn't realise that could happen in the US..

Answer (score 1):

U.S. phone numbers have three parts: A three-digit area code, a three-digit number, and a four-digit number.  Generally, these are written in the format (234)-555-1234.  If you are calling from the same area code as the person you are calling, you can omit the area code (the (234) part).  For landlines, you often need to input a 1 first if you intend to include the area code, but most cell phones don't require this.

Comment: Yep, I've read about the formatting on the Wikipedia article, but what I'm actually after is real life examples of numbers coming in on phones (from experience I guess that the format might not always be as tidy your example). Though please, if I'm wrong please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

As I say -- interesting q. Have you searched for something like "dirty north american phone format" or "how are north american phone numbers typically formatted"? Struck me as being something that has to be done often.

Google brings up this as an example: [Phone number format provider](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/PhoneNumberFormatProvider.aspx). It has a) some example formats and b) some code that actually deals with dirty or non-standard formats, and reformats them ...

Comment: I have been searching but I've been struggling for deciding what to search for.. most of the times it just bought up the correct formatting etc. I guess the keyword there is 'dirty', I'll do some more research!

Comment: Naturally, er, use with care. But yes -- seems to be a good keyword. Zipcodes, postcodes etc too ...

Comment: Mixed results so far, a search for 'dirty american phone numbers' came up with some interesting results! ;)

Answer (score 1):

So -- from my comment I guess I'd strip spaces (and hyphens) to start with, but from then on assume that you've got a right-most part of the number, and that any missing left-most parts represent increasingly wider geographic areas.

In reverse -- if the assumption works, you can create your own sample numbers by taking a standard format number and chopping groups from the left hand side -- I think.